# Kendo UI Treeview doesn't display date correctly

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to display my json from a mvc controller to be displayed on a checkboxed kendo ui treeview. The code on the asp.net mvc view and the json sent to the view are given below

```
MyDoc.cshtml code
<script>                   
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true,                       
                },
                dataSource: {
                    //type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '@Url.Content("~/Document/GetMyDocs")',
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },                        
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "id", text:"Name",
                            children: "Files"
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataTextField: [ "Name"],
                check: onCheck              
            });

json object
        [{"id":1,"Name":"Checking",
        "Files":[{"Filename":"doc10","id":"1afd5a4f-086f-44d2-9287-8098384e379e"},
        {"Filename":"doc11","id":"89ea3366-14b8-4e91-8273-6e2a51fbe516"}]},
        {"id":2,"Name":"Saving",
        "Files":[{"Filename":"doc20","id":"c7a88f5d-067e-4f20-93b6-da6eff69d532"},
        {"Filename":"doc21","id":"8a0a62ed-1b4a-4e5e-8d59-d57a975a7ab0"}]}]
```

When I view the page only the toplevel text, "Checking" and "Saving" shows. The date present under Files comes out as undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that Kendo UI uses the dataTextField: [ "Name"] for both the parent and the child node. Since the json in the child data doesn't have a field name equal to "Name" it came out as undefined. Once I changed the property, "FileName" into "Name", it worked. The Telerik's documentation is as atrocious as other third party controls. All their demos are more geared to show how easy peasy it is to create a sexy looking UI using few hard coded data than showing how to create a real world application!

Comment: Actually I found a way to keep the child node same as "FileName". Since dataTextField: [ "Name"]  is an array, I have updated it to dataTextField: [ "Name", "FileName"] . Now it works fine without the need to reame the child data property. Hope it is useful to someone!